# Android ImageView shows image smaller than it is

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, scale

at the beginning my imageview shows the right size of my image (90x90px). But when I am changing the image the imageview shows the image in another size (it still says my bitmap object is 90x90px large)

Before:  http://puu.sh/gpwPJ/61eb2e80ac.png

After: http://puu.sh/gpyO5/6e8ed42cf1.png

XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/siplaceholder"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowSpan="3"
        app:layout_column="0"/>
```

Code:

```
inputStream = getAssets().open("icons/" + "siplaceholder.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Please excuse my english but its not my native language.

<>

Well... It works know. I had to set the layout_gravitiy on fill.

Comment: Your issue is still not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: Well I want the ImageView to show diffrent pictures. At the beginning everything is fine and the image is displayed in the right way but If I change the image with ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) it displays the image much smaller than it is.

Comment: Can you show your full xml file